# SQL query will fail with actual data but will work with test data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

So, im trying insert some data into a table, I get the previous data from either GET or another SQL query (My database consists of INT and TEXT so I don't think there is an issue there).
I have a query

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO orders (USER_NAME, USER_ID, ARTIST_ID, ARTIST_NAME, PRICE, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS)
VALUES ('$user_name','$user_id','$artist_id','$artist_name','$price','$description','$comments')";
```

This `$sql2` echo's as follows

```
INSERT INTO orders (USER_NAME, USER_ID, ARTIST_ID, ARTIST_NAME, PRICE, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS) VALUES ('myname','1',''1'','Actual Name','19.99','test','tst2')
```

However, when I do

```
if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
  $conn->close();
echo "success";
exit();
} else {
  $conn->close();
echo "failed";
}
```

I get `failed` printed. But if I change the `$sql2` into

```
VALUES ('test','test','test','test','test','test','test')";
```

The query is executed successfully inserted into my database (other than the int values that turn into 0). Could someone enlighten me why this would happen?

Comment: ... but your test `data` is invalid too... numeric fields `user_id = 'test', artist_id = 'test', price = 'test'` are real numbers? Surely those are set to 0 with those values. Use parameterized queries to avoid the query quoting. If any of your values have one, it WILL break. Not to mention, the SQL issues that you are are wide open to have.

Comment: The second 1 is wrapped in two single quotes - ...('myname','1',''1'','Actu...  Is that a copy+paste mistake?

Comment: @garethhumphriesgkc ... good catch! I overlooked that.

Comment: @garethhumphriesgkc You are right, its not a copy-paste mistake.... I overlooked that. I get that specific variable using `$_SESSION[]` so I guess that's why.

Comment: On a second note, I don't know why this is happening. If I echo `echo $_SESSION['ID'];` then I get 1 without any quotes. If I do `$user_id = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_SESSION['ID']);` the sql query still fails.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason your artist_id value has a double quotation mark while other values has single quotation mark, which is probably the reason your query fails( i have bolded it):

INSERT INTO orders (USER_NAME, USER_ID, ARTIST_ID, ARTIST_NAME, PRICE, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS) VALUES ('myname','1',**''1''**,'Actual Name','19.99','test','tst2')